# Normalizing Products > Category relation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization

I am creating a SQL Server database and I have a question about one relation. I have the two entities `Product` and `Category`. The relation is one to many, so one product can have one category, but one category can have many products.

Which way is normalized and why (which normalization form)?:

1. ```
   Product { productId, productName, productPrice }
   Category { categoryId, Name }
   ```
2. ```
   Product { productId, productName, productPrice, categoryName }
   ```

If `Category` has more attributes and not only name I would make another table without doubt. But in this case I am not sure whether I have to make new table since it contains only name or leave it as `varchar` column. Isn't that going to create a lot more columns and take more space in database?

Comment: This is too broad.  What do you expect as an answer? You are asking for a textbook chapter & bespoke tutorial. Find a textbook, show your steps following it & ask a question where stuck. Even to explain why you have not given enough information is too much. (Give & justify your FDs.)

Comment: Design 1 does not relate product to category--don't you want a categoryId in Product? Design 2 does have categoryIds--do you want them, or not? If they don't matter, why have them in design 1? Do you understand that replacing values by ids & adding an id-to-value column is *not* "normalization"? Please clarify. PS Are category ids 1:1 with category names? (But--this would be answered by giving FDs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create the following two tables:

```
1. Category { categoryId, Name }
2. Product { productId, categoryId, productName, productPrice }
```

Considering that the categoryId in category table is a Primary Key, you should creata a foreign key constraint on categoryId in the Products table referencing to categoryId in the category table.